# How to put this timer in a loop? JS

Tags: javascript, loops, timer, settimeout, countdown

```
  function countdown() {
        var secs = 60;
        function timer() {
            var counter = document.getElementById("counter");
            secs--;
            counter.innerHTML = "0:" + (secs< 10 ? "0" : "") + String(secs);
            if( secs > 0 ) {
                setTimeout(timer, 1000);
            } else {
                alert("Game over, you did not get to finish the game on time :( ");
                document.getElementById('memory_board').innerHTML = "";
                        newBoard();
            }
        }
        timer();
    }

    countdown();
```

How can I place this code in a loop? It's basically a timer which starts at 60 and ends at 0, and when that happens, the game restarts. I have no problem with the game restarting, but I just don't know how to put this code on a loop. I have looked in codeacademy and it says for a loop I have to use

```
for (var x; y;z ) {
    //code
}
```

where x is the start y is where it ends and z is how does it change. Please help me work this out, I'm a little confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to look into using `setInterval`.  It calls a given function every n millaseconds.  You could structure your countdown function like so:

```
function countdown(seconds) {
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        if (seconds < 0) clearInterval(interval); //break the interval
        seconds--;
        //code
    }, 1000); //time in millaseconds to wait
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would just need to place this code in a javascript file that is referenced in your html file. Or you can just wrap this javascript code in a `<script> </script>` tag. This should make the code run when you load the webpage.

If you are trying to make the function `countdown()` run in a loop based on time, you can also try `setInterval(countdown(), time_in_milliseconds);`

setInterval will run the passed in function every x milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/michael_0815/nsu77w92/)

```
   setInterval(function() {
    countdown();
    },60000);

function countdown() {
        var secs = 60;
        function timer() {
            var counter = document.getElementById("counter");
            secs--;
            counter.innerHTML = "0:" + (secs< 10 ? "0" : "") + String(secs);
            if( secs > 0 ) {
                setTimeout(timer, 1000);
            } else {
                alert("Game over, you did not get to finish the game on time :( ");
                document.getElementById('memory_board').innerHTML = "";
                        newBoard();
            }
        }
        timer();
    }

    countdown();
```

Comment: The OP wants the counter to decrease every second, and the code you supplied runs the function once per minute, without decreasing the counter.

Comment: Sorry, but you really should read and understand the code again before you downvote, and maybe try it with the DEMO to see that it does exactly what the OP wants... @David

Answer (score 0):

first of all, don't use counter-base count-down in javascript, since 
setTimeout(foo, 1000) is not that accurate then you thought.
FYI: http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/

to modify your code so it can countdown properly, try the following instead:

```
function countdown() {
    var secs = 60,
        startTime = new Date().getTime(), // <-- new here
        endTime = startTime + secs * 1000; // <-- new here
    function timer() {
        var counter = document.getElementById("counter");
        secs = Math.floor((endTime - new Date().getTime())/1000); // <-- modify here
        counter.innerHTML = "0:" + (secs< 10 ? "0" : "") + String(secs);
        if( secs > 0 ) {
            setTimeout(timer, 1000);
        } else {
            alert("Game over, you did not get to finish the game on time :( ");
            document.getElementById('memory_board').innerHTML = "";
                    newBoard();
        }
    }
    timer();
}

countdown();
```

to have this code in a loop, it might be good to wrapped it as an object and pass what you 
want to do after countdown is over.

```
function newCounter(_secs, _callback) {
    var executeWhenEnd = _callback,
        secs = _secs;
    function countdown() {
        var startTime = new Date().getTime(), // <-- new here
            endTime = startTime + secs * 1000; // <-- new here
        function timer() {
            var counter = document.getElementById("counter");
            secs = Math.floor((endTime - new Date().getTime())/1000); // <-- modify here
            counter.innerHTML = "0:" + (secs< 10 ? "0" : "") + String(secs);
            if( secs > 0 ) {
                setTimeout(timer, 1000);
            } else {
                callback();
            }
        }
        timer();
    }
    return {
        countdown: countdown
        };
}
```

so every time you want to have a counter, you can get a new counter and start countdown 
whenever you want.
example:

```
var counter1 = newCounter(60, function(){
         //fire after 60 seconds
         alert("Game over, you did not get to finish the game on time :( ");
         document.getElementById('memory_board').innerHTML = "";
         newBoard();
    }),
    counter2 = newCounter(5, function() {
        //fire after 5 seconds.
    });
counter1.countdown(); // start countdown
counter2.countdown(); // start countdown
```

Hope it helps.